# Add new objects in arraylist to the other arraylist while the second one do not have these new objects

Tags: java, arraylist

If I have two `ArrayList` one for `currentScanWifiList<Router>`
this contains the current wifi scan Routers data 
and the the second have the same type `allUniqueRoutersList<Router>`
used to add the new routers existing in `currentScanWifiList` and do not exist in allUniqueRoutersList
the comparing between the routers through equaling its bssid

```
public class Router {
    private String bssid;//identifier
    private String ssid;
    private double x;
    private double y;
    private double meanRss;
setter and getter....
}
    for (int x = 0; x < currentScanList.size(); x++) {
        Router currentTempRouter = currentScanList.get(x);
        for (int y = 0; y < allUniqueRoutersList.size(); y++) {
            Router allTempRouter = currentScanList.get(y);
            if (!currentTempRouter.getBssid().equals(allTempRouter.getBssid())) {
                allUniqueRoutersList.add(currentScanList.get(x));
                break;
            } 
        }
    }
```

I tried this code but it is not working, it add all objects to `allUniqueRoutersList`
not the new ones only 
what should I do to compare between the two arraylist elements using bssid

Comment: You can create `Set set=new HashSet()` and put all unique wifi there, and after that export them in your list if it needs or compare with list consist every wifi

Comment: You can use `HashSet`, with `equals` and `hashcode` implemented to compare `Router`  based on `bssid`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you add the router immediately, e.g. you don't really loop:

```
for (int x = 0; x < currentScanList.size(); x++) {
            Router currentTempRouter = currentScanList.get(x);
            boolean found = false;
            for (int y = 0; y < allUniqueRoutersList.size(); y++) {
                Router allTempRouter = allUniqueRoutersList.get(y);
                if (currentTempRouter.getBssid().equals(allTempRouter.getBssid())) {
                    found = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(!found){
                allUniqueRoutersList.add(currentTempRouter);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Store your `bssid`'s from your `allUniqueRoutersList` in a set and iterate over your `currentScanList` and check for each router if the bssid is in the set, if not add the router to your `allUniqueRoutersList` :

```
Set<String> bssidSet = allUniqueRoutersList.stream()
                      .map(router->router.getBssid())
                      .collect(Collectors.toSet());

  for(Router r : currentScanList){
        if(!bssidSet.contains(r.getBssid())){
            allUniqueRoutersList.add(r);
        }
    }
```